# Solve the system $x^2-3xy+2y^2+x-y=0$, $2x^2-2xy-3y^2-2x+5y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system of equations:($x,y \in \Bbb R)$
>   $$\begin{cases} x^2-3xy+2y^2+x-y=0     \\ 2x^2-2xy-3y^2-2x+5y=0
>     \end{cases}$$

It's easily seen that $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are two set of answers,but I can't analyze it to find all answers...
Also,trying to delete $x^2$ gives an equation in terms of $y^2$ whose delta is always positive

Comment: Did you try graphing those two conic sections to see how many intersections there are?

Comment: No,I prefer pure algebraic methods

Comment: Since the highest order is 2, you can try rewriting them as quadratic forms ,finding their eigensystems and switch to a suitable basis.

Comment: Right now I could decompose an equation derived from deleting  $x^2$ which yields: $y=1$ or $y=\frac47x$

Comment: No unnecessary `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` in titles, please.

Comment: Ok,I used \begin{array} instead.

Comment: Which is as horrible. Please do not erase edits that make your post better (as you would know is you tried to get minimally informed on these matters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completing the squares for the first equation help to write the first equation as $$(x-y)(x-2y+1)=0.$$

Now you can discuss cases: $x=y$ or $x=2y-1$ ...

Answer (score 2):

As I observe from graph.
There is only there are three  solutions of the equation
(0,0),(1,1) and(7,4)

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l} x^2-3xy+2y^2+x-y=0     \\ 
2x^2-2xy-3y^2-2x+5y=0
    \end{array}\right.$$

substitute $x=X+1;\;y=Y+1$ in the first equation

$(X+1)^2+-3 (X+1) (Y+1)+2 (Y+1)^2+X+1-Y-1=0$

becomes $X^2 - 3 X Y + 2 Y^2=0$

$X=x-1;\;Y=y-1$

Solve $X=Y;\;X=2Y$ and then $x=y;\;x-1=2y-2\to x=2y-1$

Plug in the second equation and find, for $x=y$

$3 y-3 y^2=0\to y=0;\;y=1$

first two solutions $(0,0);\;(1;\;1)$

for $x=2y-1$

$y^2-5 y+4=0\to y=1;\;y=4$

The other two solutions are $(1,1);\;(7,4)$